# WebView Unable to disable scroll, yet retain links and button in PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uiwebview

Would like to disable scrolling in PDF but retain links and button in PDF. Had tried other threads' solutions as follow, but none of it work for me:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

Neither,

```
[[_Presentation scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[[_Presentation scrollView] setBounces:NO];
```

Nor,

```
[(UIScrollView *)[[_Presentation subviews] lastObject] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[(UIScrollView *)[[_Presentation subviews] lastObject] setBounces:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve this issue. Here is the steps:

Add UIScrollViewDelegate in the .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController  <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In .m file, ViewController -> viewDidLoad add following line to take over ScrollView Delegate

```
_Presentation.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

In .m file, add following scroll event below viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {   
[[_Presentation scrollView] setScrollEnabled:NO];
[[_Presentation scrollView] setBounces:NO];}
```